# Excel VBA - While closing Temp workbook excel closes main workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So i have workbook  'A' where macro runs to copy a range and paste it in new workbook 'B'
When i try closing workbook 'B' by close(X) button it closes workbook 'A'

Kindly help!

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Sheets("Hub").Range("B9:C20").Copy
'Add Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
```

Comment: Code works properly for me.  (I.e. clicking the "X" closes workbook B without saving it anywhere.)

Comment: Why are trying to close workbook B without naming it? It makes no sense to open a new workbook, paste some data into it and then close it without saving it.

Comment: @Jeeped It might be that workbook B is just being used as a temporary "report" being displayed to the user, and the user presses the "X" to close it once they have seen it.  i.e. a **big** MsgBox.  (It might not be too, but that was one scenario that I came up with where this might be desirable.)

Comment: @YowE3K Bro! you are exactly right! I still face the problem!